# Repository function returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-repositories, mongorepository

I have this repository function:

```
public interface CommunityRepository extends MongoRepository<Community,String> {
    @Query(value="{ 'builder_id' : 1}", fields="{ 'name' : 1, 'description' : 1, 'slogan' : 1, 'address' : 1, 'numberOfHouses' : 1}")
    List<Community> findAllByBuilderId(List<String> builderId);
}
```

Here how I call it from service:

```
List<String> builderId = new ArrayList<String>();
builderId.add("6127db1d94ae73194a990444");
builderId.add("5f9852ce93834b1fc01f6573");
builderId.add("602db8e7b05b804313f9ft67");

List<Community> communities = underTest.findAllByBuilderId(builderId);
```

And here Community class:

```
@Data
@Document("communities")
@Slf4j
public class Community {
    @Id
    private String id = null;
    @NotBlank(message = "Must not be blank")
    @Size(max = 50, message = "Max length is 50 characters")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 400, message = "Max length is 200 characters")
    private String description;
    private List<String> tags;
    @Field("builder_id")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-fA-F0-9]{24}", message = "Wrong id format")
    private String builderId;
}
```

The communities list is always empty, but there are a few items associated with that `builder id`.

Any idea why the communities list is always empty?

Comment: Your query is completely unparameterized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed a parameter in your query and you have only the static value 1.

`{ 'builder_id' : 1}` means search statically for `builder_id = 1`

What you want is
`{ 'builder_id' : { $in: ?0 } }` where you say builder_id must be one of the elements contained in the first parameter provided by your method (index starts from 0) so it is `?0`

So you query in the end must be

```
  @Query(value="{ 'builder_id' : { $in: ?0 } } )
    List<Community> findAllByBuilderId(List<String> builderId);
```

If this is not accepted try with `{$in: [?0]}`